# For guitar sight reading, how do you not confuse between 3rd and 4th string?

Tags: guitar, sight-reading

I am currently working on sight reading as a beginner guitar player.
I keep placing fingers wrongly between 3rd and 4th strings.
I try to keep my fingers near to the fretboard, have a steady hand.
But still this mistake keeps happening.

Is there a good way to fix this problem?

Comment: Add an example of what you are trying to play? It might be important because: maybe you use bad fingering, or the music is just too complex? Maybe there are specific chord voicings which you could change? Or anything else I can't even think about.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure from the question if you have trouble making sense of the... tablature? (what kind of notation are you playing from? staff, tablature, chord symbols/diagrams?) in time, or you know exactly which string you should play but keep missing your aim with the hand (and if the latter, which hand).

Comment: When you say **sight-reading**, do you mean seeing unfamiliar music for the very first time and playing it as well as you possibly can, or do you mean playing whilst reading from sheet music? They are two different skills.

Comment: No real silver bullet I'm sorry. Just loads a practice, followed by loads more. Also, there's a lot of info. missing from the question - could you clarify at least the points noted in the comments.

Comment: Is it a proprioception issue? Also, be careful so you do not rest your arm on the guitar edge since the prolonged pressure it exerts on on the nerves and tendons in the forearm can cause issues in your arm.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a case of "practice more" I'm afraid. Finger independence and muscle memory comes with time and practice, and there's no real way around this. Some general advice to make it easier:

- Play the song a little slower - making sure you don't rush is key to encouraging best practices and discouraging bad technique.
- Play to a metronome - to encourage consistency.
- Film yourself - being able to play back what you're doing could highlight any habits which you don't realise you're doing (weird hand position, fingers floundering more than you realise, etc). It'll also be handy for figuring out if you're struggling with specific fingers more than others.
- Play songs you already know - taking a break from practicing specific things gives you a chance to reset rather than getting too frustrated (and is generally more fun).
- Practice general scales and finger independence exercises - personally I'm a big fan of John Petrucci's "Rock Discipline" book/video series. Doing the kinds of exercises that Petrucci outlines is excellent for getting more natural at finding the right strings/frets without issues.

If I have misunderstood your question and you are struggling with tablature (rather than literally struggling to play the 3rd/4th strings) - you may need to look for better tablature or make the tab bigger?

Answer (score 1):

This is understandable because those are the two middle strings so they are farthest away from the edges of the fingerboard. It really doesn’t matter whether you are sight reading or playing something you know. Here are a few tips that might be useful:

Keep in mind that the 3rd string is on the lower half of the fingerboard and the 4th is on the upper. Having this mental image will cause you to you reach higher towards the 4th and lower towards the 3rd.

Try and memorize the feeling of your hand position when playing each string. I’m referring to the thumb position (which actually should be fairly constant) and the curvature of your wrist and fingers.

Practice playing different scales on each individual string up and down the fingerboard. Also practice playing segments of scales back and forth between the two strings.